# iOS game moving object up and down

Tags: ios, object, screen, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a game, something slightly similar to Jetpack Joyride. At certain points it will have an object that the player has to fly between - like the pipes on flappy birds. I have managed to create the pipe objects however I wish for the objects to move up and down on the screen, making it harder for the player to jump between. My code for placing the objects is:

```
// Maths
float availableSpace = HEIGHT(self) - HEIGHT(floor);
float maxVariance = availableSpace - (2*OBSTACLE_MIN_HEIGHT) - VERTICAL_GAP_SIZE;
float variance = [Math randomFloatBetween:0 and:maxVariance];

// Bottom object placement
float minBottomPosY = HEIGHT(floor) + OBSTACLE_MIN_HEIGHT - HEIGHT(self);
float bottomPosY = minBottomPosY + variance;
bottomPipe.position = CGPointMake(xPos,bottomPosY);
bottomPipe.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:CGRectMake(0,0, WIDTH(bottomPipe) , HEIGHT(bottomPipe))];
bottomPipe.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = blockBitMask;
bottomPipe.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerBitMask;

// Top object placement
topPipe.position = CGPointMake(xPos,bottomPosY + HEIGHT(bottomPipe) + VERTICAL_GAP_SIZE);
topPipe.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithEdgeLoopFromRect:CGRectMake(0,0, WIDTH(topPipe), HEIGHT(topPipe))];

topPipe.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = blockBitMask;
topPipe.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = playerBitMask;
```

How would I go about moving the objects up and down?
Thanks for any help :)

Comment: Do you know how to move a node ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All such operations on a node are done using `SKAction` objects. Read up on the SKAction class [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKAction_Ref/Reference/Reference.html).

In your case, using an SKAction to move the nodes up and down would go something like this:

```
SKAction *actionMoveUp = [SKAction moveByX:0 y:20 duration:0.5];
SKAction *actionMoveDown = [actionMoveUp reversedAction];
SKAction *actionMoveUpDown = [SKAction sequence:@[actionMoveUp, actionMoveDown]];
SKAction *actionMoveDownRepeat = [SKAction repeatActionForever:actionMoveUpDown]; 

[bottomPipe runAction:actionMoveDownRepeat];
[topPipe runAction:actionMoveDownRepeat];
```

The code given above will make your top and bottom pipe go up and down by a factor of 20 pixels repeatedly.